# A crate is exported but "use" throws compilation errors

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In Cargo I have this:

```
postgres = "0.11.7"
```

And in a submodule *.rs

```
extern crate postgres;

use postgres::{Connection, Error, FromSql, SslMode};
use postgres::Result as PgResult;
```

And the compilation errors:

```
error: unresolved import `postgres::Connection`. Did you mean `self::postgres`? [E0432]
unresolved import `postgres::Error`. Did you mean `self::postgres`? [E0432]

error: unresolved import `postgres::SslMode`. Did you mean `self::postgres`? [E0432]
```

And the similar ones.

Comment: Did you placed `extern crate postgres;` in `lib.rs` or `main.rs`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to put `extern crate` directives to any module, it is both more idiomatic and more convenient to put it to your *crate root*, usually `lib.rs` or `main.rs`. Then your `use` statements will work as they are now.

The reason for this problem is that you have put `extern crate postgres` to one of submodules of the root crate:

```
mod submodule {
    extern crate postgres;

    use postgres::...;
}
```

This means that the full path to `postgres` module would be `submodule::postgres`, not just `postgres` (remember, paths in `use` directives are by default absolute), so you should use either `use submodule::postgres::whatever;` or `use self::postgres::whatever;` (the latter form is an example of relative paths in `use` statement). However, as I said before, this is not idiomatic and should be avoided.

Comment: One of the caveats here is that `use` is relative to the `root`, while other path is relative to `self`. This proves to be very confusing to new comers.